# Get a field value from a document in firestore in c++

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, c++14

How can I get a field value from a document in fire store in c++?

```
db->collection("users").document(x).Get('fieldname');
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/firestore/document-snapshot#public-functions), you should be able to retrieve a specific field from the document using the following public functions:

`Get(const char *field, ServerTimestampBehavior stb)`

`Get(const std::string & field, ServerTimestampBehavior stb)`

`Get(const FieldPath & field, ServerTimestampBehavior stb)`